# Error al Ejecutar python3 manage.py makemigrations

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

espero puedan ayudarme, al momento de ejecutar el comando del título me aparece el siguiente error en la consola:

```
Migrations for 'notas':
  notas/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Empresa
    - Create model Programador
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 224, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 248, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 367, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable
```

PD.: estoy usando django 2.2.16, python 3.8.6 en ubuntu 20.10
PD2.: si hace las migraciones.
Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Amigo es mejor que muestres el código para visualizar el error, mostrando solo el error es muy difícil

Answer (score 0):

Parece que tu error se encuentra en el settings, en la parte de DATABASES, verifica que esta parte este correcta con os.path.join:

```
'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')
```

Y que este haciendo el import os en tu settings.

De ser posible comparte tu settings de la base de datos para verificar bien.

Answer (score 0):

Hola solucione el error revisando detalladamente mi archivo Models.py si usas Sublime Text3 este editor de texto no reconoce mayúsculas, algún tipo de datos mal digitado en tu creación de models.py que son las tablas que creas en "sqlite" que lo trae por defecto. y por ultimo el orden de la creación de los modelos ejemplo.

class Estudiante(models.Model):> esta es tu tabla
dni = models.CharField(max_length=5)> este es el cronograma que debe de llevar tu BD.
Y donde específicamente están los errores en la aparte ultima del código no te quiebres mucho la cabeza con los file:"lib/python/" in module 22.
espero te sirva